# Best way to interrupt embedded python execution in C++

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, extend

I am building a C++ application which allows the user to input Python code to directly interact with objects in the C++ environment. Currently, I have been able to get the following working:

I have a set of embedded functions in C++ which can be imported as a module into Python and called.

I am taking each of the embedded function calls from the Python code and adding them to a 'command queue' list variable in C++ which can then be iterated over once that it has been verified that the list of instructions is less than 100 long. However, I can't seem to find an elegant way to avoid the entire application crashing when I attempt to do this.

PythonHandler.cpp:

```
List<String> pythonCommandQueue;

PyObject* self_Move(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Number of instructions: %i\n", pythonCommandQueue.Size()+1);
    if (pythonCommandQueue.Size() > 100) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Number of instructions exceeds limit! Restarting...");
        PyErr_SetInterrupt();
        fprintf(stderr, "DONE!\n");
    } else {
        char* direction;
        // Get direction from Python parameters tuple
        if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &direction))
            return NULL;

        // Run function on actor from VPPO
        if (String(direction) == String("up")) {
            pythonCommandQueue.Push("up");
        }
        else if (String(direction) == String("down")) {
            pythonCommandQueue.Push("down");
        }
        else if (String(direction) == String("left")) {
            pythonCommandQueue.Push("left");
        }
        else if (String(direction) == String("right")) {
            pythonCommandQueue.Push("right");
        }
        else {
            return NULL;
        }
        return Py_BuildValue("Oi", Py_True);
    }
}

PyMethodDef SelfMethods[] = {
    {"move", self_Move, METH_VARARGS, "Move actor from VPPO."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

void PythonHandler::Start()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    Py_InitModule("self", SelfMethods);
}

int PythonHandler::RunPyScript()
{
    char* userScriptFilename = "run.py";
    PyObject* PyFileObject = PyFile_FromString(userScriptFilename, "r");

    if (PyFileObject != NULL) {
        PyRun_SimpleFileEx(PyFile_AsFile(PyFileObject), userScriptFilename, 1);
    }
    else {
        PyErr_Print();
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load \"%s\"\n", userScriptFilename);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

run.py:

```
import self
self.move("up")
```

What is the best way to ensure that the attempt to execute Python (PyRun_SimpleFileEx) is cancelled, without the C++ environment crashing?